# which status code should be returned for null parameter

Tags: googlebot, http-code-400

having a website with many urls in js code (ajax calls),

the google bot is calling these but without the necessary parameters

atm 200 code is returned and the html for the error page, and this is considered a soft 404 (which is bad)

what http status code should be returned for this situation, example:

`example.com/Edit?id=32` // 200  correct use of url

`example.com/Edit` // that's how google bot is calling, which code should be returned ?

it's actually called in js like this `$.get('example.com/Edit', params, successFunc)`
    so the bot can't know about the parameters

is it 400, 404 or 422 ?

Comment: I don't think that Googlebot is going to treat any of those error codes differently.   From the perspective of Googlebot itself, it probably doesn't matter what you use.

Comment: @stephenOstermiller thank you, that could be an answer (your statement)

Comment: There is probably a correct status to use from a semantic perspective.